# Find index of $\mathbb{Z}[\theta]$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{k}$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Find **index** of $\mathbb{Z}[\theta]$ in  $\mathbb{Z}_{k}$ i.e $[ \mathbb{Z}_{k}:\mathbb{Z}[\theta]]$, where $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5}),\theta=\sqrt{5}$

As $5\equiv 1 \pmod 4$ the ring of integers of $K$ will have form : $Z_{k}=\mathbb{Z}+\mathbb{Z}\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}=\{a+b\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\;|a,b\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ while

$Z[ \theta]=\mathbb{Z}+\mathbb{Z}\sqrt{5}=\{a+b\sqrt{5}\;|a,b\in\mathbb{Z}\}$

Then clearly $Z[\theta]\subset Z_{k}$

If I let $\alpha=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$

Then  $Z_{k}=\mathbb{Z}+\mathbb{Z}\alpha$ and $Z[\theta]=\mathbb{Z}+\mathbb{Z}2\alpha$

Q1) Can I consider the above rings as free abelian groups of rank 2? the $\mathbb{Z}$-bases are $\{1,\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\}$ and $\{1,\sqrt{5}\}$ respectively ?

Q2)
 Can I use thm (Stewart-Tall) $\Bigl|G/ H\Bigr|=|\det(a_{ij})|$??

Or is there any faster method? 
In my notes I have

$Z[\theta]=\mathbb{Z}+\mathbb{Z}(2\alpha-1)=\mathbb{Z}+\mathbb{Z}2\alpha$

$a+b(2\alpha-1)=a-b+2b\alpha$ and

$[ \mathbb{Z}_{k}:\mathbb{Z}[\theta]]=2$

But I do not see it...

Can someone explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Q1): Yes, they are free abelian groups of rank 2.

(Q2): There is a faster method. Focus first on the simpler case of the groups of rank 1 given by $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$ and $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}/2]$. I hope it's clear that the first has index 2 in the second.

Your case is essentially the same. Note that an arbitrary element of $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ is of the form $c+d\sqrt{5}$, where $c$ and $d$ are both integers or both half-integers. With this you should be able to describe the two cosets of $\mathbb{Z}[\theta]$ in $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$.